Find the number of cycles of length 3

Given the count. Find the number of cycles of length 3.

Input format: The first line contains two integers n and m (1 < n, m ≤ 3✕10⁵) — the number of vertices and edges, respectively. Each of the next m lines contains two integers from 1 to n — the vertices that are connected by the corresponding edge. It is guaranteed that the graph has no loops or multiple edges.
Output format: Print one number - the answer.
Example input:
6 6
1 2
2 3
3 1
4 2
3 4
5 1

For this input, the answer is 2 (because 1→2→3→1 and 2→3→4→2)

My code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);

    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vector<vector<int>> adj(n + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        adj[u].push_back(v);
        adj[v].push_back(u);
    }

    int cycle_count = 0;

    for (int u = 1; u <= n; ++u) {
        for (int v : adj[u]) {
            if (v > u) {
                unordered_set<int> neighbors(adj[u].begin(), adj[u].end());
                for (int w : adj[v]) {
                    if (w > v && neighbors.find(w) != neighbors.end()) {
                        ++cycle_count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << cycle_count << endl;

    return 0;
}

The code produces the correct result, but is too slow. Are there any ideas on how to optimize it or is there some algorithm that will speed up the program?

All C++20 code is valid C++17 - which are you actually targeting?

I find it strange that the graph has "no loops" when we're required to actually count some loops - that's clearly an error in the problem statement!

I'm guessing it means no trivial loops that connect a node to itself - please clarify if that's not the intent.

I meant to say that C++17 code is valid in C++20 - I don't know why I wrote it the wrong way around.  [tag:c++20] can be safely removed (unless you no longer care about C++17 in which case remove that tag instead).

The previous review is comprehensive, and the proposed solution meets the requirements of the task. We can test the worst case scenario to see that.
We have a complete graph with m = 3✕10⁵ edges in the worst case because every unordered vertex triplet makes a 3-cycle. There are exactly n(n - 1)(n - 2)/6 such triplets. Since m = n(n - 1)/2, we have n < 776.
I propose a solution that runs noticeably faster on my pc in the worst case:
unsigned countLength3Cycles() {
    using Edges = std::vector<pair<unsigned, unsigned>>;
    using Graph = std::vector<vector<unsigned>>;

    unsigned nVertices;
    unsigned nEdges;
    cin >> nVertices >> nEdges;

    Edges edges;
    edges.reserve(nEdges);
    for (auto i = 0u; i < nEdges; ++i) {
        unsigned from;
        unsigned to;
        std::cin >> from >> to;
        if (from > to)
            std::swap(from, to);
        edges.emplace_back(from, to);
    }
    std::sort(std::begin(edges), std::end(edges));

    auto nCycles = 0u;
    Graph g(nVertices + 1);
    for (auto [from, to] : edges) { // (1)
        for (auto i = 0u, j = 0u; i < g[from].size() && j < g[to].size(); ) { // (2)
            if (auto lhs = g[from][i], rhs = g[to][j]; lhs <= rhs) {
                ++i;
                nCycles += lhs == rhs;
            }
            else
                ++j;
        }
        g[to].push_back(from);
    }
    return nCycles;
}

The intuition is straightforward.
First, sort the edges to fix the orientation of cycles, edges = ((u1, v1), (u2, v2), ...), ui < vi, ui < uj, i < j.
Take for example a sorted sequence ((1,4),(1,5),(2,4),(2,5),(4,5),...).
When we get to the element (4,5) in the loop (1), the corresponding elements of the graph g will be g[4] = {1, 2} and g[5] = {1, 2}.
And the inner loop (2) merely counts the number of equal elements in the sorted sequences.

Great solution! It turns out that the compiler liked your method! Thank you very much for the idea for a solution

Please don't drag the whole of std into the global namespace with using namespace std; - that completely eliminates all the benefits of namespacing and makes your code less predictable.
It's hard to unit-test the code because it's all written directly in main().  I recommend extracting the computation as an independently-testable function, and using main() just to obtain the inputs and display the results.
These tweaks appear to be premature optimisation:

ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(0);


There's no point streamlining I/O when it's not the bottleneck in the code.
Always check for success of streaming input before using the streamed-to values:
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    if (!std::cin) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid input\n";  // TODO: friendly re-read
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

The variable names aren't helping me to read this code.  m and n come directly from the problem description, but we're free to use more informative names in the code (perhaps vertex_count and edge_count, for example).  adj, u, v, the other u, the other v, and w are all opaque at first glance.
It seem strange to be using signed int for non-negative quantities, even when they are guaranteed to be less than the 32767 guaranteed representable by int.
It seems silly to store our adjacency sets as std::vector, only to transform into std::unordered_set in the inner loop (which is a slow operation, as it involves memory allocation).
We're storing every edge twice, but we can solve the problem with only one entry for each edge - it helps to maintain a consistent order, such as from smaller to larger vertex number.  That greatly reduces our search space.
A related optimisation might be to use plain (ordered) set so we can eliminate large parts of search space simply by knowing the relative order of elements.
Since neighbours is a set, we don't need the unwieldy neighbors.find(w) != neighbors.end() to determine whether it contains an element - neighbours.count(w) is equivalent and clearer.
There's no need to flush output using std::endl immediately before program exit - std::cout's destructor will flush anyway.
We don't need return 0; at the end of main() - just running off the end of the function has the same effect (for main() only, not for other functions!).

Improved code
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

using VertexNumber = unsigned;

class graph
{
    using edges = std::vector<VertexNumber>;
    std::vector<edges> vertices; // one entry for each starting node
    bool sorted = true;

public:
    explicit graph(VertexNumber max_vertex)
        : vertices{max_vertex + 1}
    {}

    void insert(VertexNumber from, VertexNumber to)
    {
        if (to < from) {
            std::swap(from, to);
        }
        vertices[from].push_back(to);
        sorted = false;
    }

    bool is_connected(VertexNumber from, VertexNumber to) const
    {
        if (to < from) {
            std::swap(from, to);
        }
        return std::ranges::binary_search(vertices[from], (to));
    }

    void prepare_for_query()
    {
        if (!sorted) {
            for (auto& vertex: vertices) {
                std::ranges::sort(vertex);
            }
            sorted = true;
        }
    }

    std::size_t count_three_node_cycles() const
    {
        if (!sorted) {
            throw std::logic_error{"Graph must be sorted before querying"};
        }

        std::size_t cycle_count = 0;
        for (auto const& vertex: vertices) {
            // Find all pairs of nodes reachable from this one
            for (auto first = vertex.begin();  first != vertex.end();  ++first) {
                for (auto second = first;  second != vertex.end();  ++second) {
                    cycle_count += is_connected(*first, *second);
                }
            }
        }
        return cycle_count;
    }
};



#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    VertexNumber vertex_count, edge_count;
    std::cin >> vertex_count >> edge_count;
    if (!std::cin) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid input\n";  // TODO: friendly re-read
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    graph g{vertex_count};

    while (edge_count--) {
        VertexNumber from, to;
        std::cin >> from >> to;
        if (!std::cin) {
            std::cerr << "Input format error\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        g.insert(from, to);
    }

    g.prepare_for_query();
    std::cout << g.count_three_node_cycles() << '\n';
}

Now we can exercise with a more aggressive set of tests:
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    constexpr VertexNumber vertex_count = 30'000;
    {
        // test 1: a big star
        graph g{vertex_count};
        for (VertexNumber n = 1;  n < vertex_count;  ++n) {
            g.insert(0, n);
        }
        g.prepare_for_query();
        if (g.count_three_node_cycles() != 0) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    {
        // test 2: a big loop
        graph g{vertex_count};
        g.insert(vertex_count, 0);
        for (VertexNumber n = 1;  n < vertex_count;  ++n) {
            g.insert(n, n+1);
        }
        g.prepare_for_query();
        if (g.count_three_node_cycles() != 0) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    {
        // test 3: mostly 3-cycles
        graph g{vertex_count};
        g.insert(0, 1);
        for (VertexNumber n = 2;  n <= vertex_count;  ++n) {
            g.insert(0, n);
            g.insert(1, n);
        }
        g.prepare_for_query();
        if (g.count_three_node_cycles() != vertex_count - 1) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
}

When I use this to exercise the code, my system completes in about 1.9 seconds, compared to 182 with the original algorithm (about 2 orders of magnitude improvement).
Compilation flags used:
g++-14 -std=c++23 -fPIC -gdwarf-4 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wmissing-braces -Wconversion  -Wuseless-cast -Weffc++ -O3 -march=native    292469.cpp    -o 292469


This code still works the same as mine... This algorithm did not help

Could you show me another algorithm that made the program run faster?

sync_with_stdio(false) and cin.tie(0) are tricks to make iostream input faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull

@qwr, there's no point micro-optimising the I/O at this stage.

It's just standard in competition programming templates. It does make a big difference when there's a ton of I/O.

@Dmitry I've updated with some benchmark results.

Apparently the compiler from the teacher needs a different algorithm and this is not a problem with optimizing this code... For some reason it works slowly

My approach scales as O(m² log m), I think.  But it doesn't create an expensive set object in an inner loop like the original.

@TobySpeight You're right; I didn't read the code carefully. In general, though, problems with constraints set to 10^5 do not permit quadratic solutions or worse as the time limit for online judges is usually 1 second.

This can be solved with square root decomposition in O(m√m).
We will have separate procedures for handling nodes based on their outdegree. If   a node has outdegree at most √m, we can run a quadratic loop over all pairs of its immediate neighbors and check if they are connected. This takes O(m√m).
We have already counted all cycles containing at least one node with outdegree not larger than √m; next, we consider cycles containing only nodes with outdegree greater than √m. Note that the number of such nodes is O(√m), so we can simply brute force over all triples in O(m√m).
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
constexpr unsigned MAXN = 3e5 + 1;
std::unordered_set<int> adj[MAXN];
int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    const unsigned threshold = std::sqrt(m);
    for (int i = 0, u, v; i < m; ++i) {
        std::cin >> u >> v;
        adj[u].insert(v);
        adj[v].insert(u);
    }
    std::size_t cycles{};
    std::vector<int> large;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (adj[i].size() <= threshold) {
            for (auto it = adj[i].begin(); it != adj[i].end(); ++it)
                for (auto it2 = it; ++it2 != adj[i].end();)
                    cycles += adj[*it].count(*it2);
        } else {
            large.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < large.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < large.size(); ++j)
            if (adj[large[i]].count(large[j]))
                for (std::size_t k = j + 1; k < large.size(); ++k)
                    cycles += adj[large[i]].count(large[k]) && adj[large[j]].count(large[k]);
    std::cout << cycles << '\n';
}

